# Regex if then without else in ripgrep

Tags: regex, ripgrep

I am trying to match some methods in a bunch of python scripts if certain conditions are met. First thing i am looking at is if `import re` exists in a file, and if it does, then find all cases of `re.sub(something)`. I tried following the documentation [here](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/using-conditionals-inside-ruby-regular-expressions/) on how to use if then without else regexs, but cant seem to make it work with ripgrep with or without pcre2.

My next approach was to use groups, so `rg -n "(^import.+re)|(re\.sub.+)" -r '$2'`, but the issue with this approach is that because the first import group matches, i get a lot of empty files back in my output. The `$2` is being handled correctly.

I am hoping to avoid doing a or group capture, and use the regex if option if possible.

To summarize, what I am hoping for is, if `import re` appears anywhere in a file, then search for `re\.sub.+` and output only the matching files and lines using `ripgrep`. Using ripgrep is a hard dependency.

Some sample code:

```
import re

for i in range(10):
    re.match(something)
    print(i)

re.sub(something)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished pretty easily with a shell pipeline and xargs. The idea is to use the first regex as a filter for which files to search in, and the second regex to show the places where `re.sub` occurs.

Here are three Python files to test with.

`import-without-sub.py` has an `import re` but no `re.sub`:

```py
import re

for i in range(10):
    re.match(something)
    print(i)
```

`import-with-sub.py` has both an `import re` and an `re.sub`:

```py
import re

for i in range(10):
    re.match(something)
    print(i)

re.sub(something)
```

And finally, `no-import.py` has no `import re` but does have a `re.sub`:

```py
for i in range(10):
    re.match(something)
    print(i)

re.sub(something)
```

And now here's the command to show only matches of `re.sub` in files that contain `import re`:

```sh
rg '^import\s+re$' --files-with-matches --null | xargs -0 rg -F 're.sub('
```

`--files-with-matches` and `--null` print out all matching file paths separated by a `NUL` byte. `xargs -0` then reads those file paths and turns them into arguments to be given to `rg -F 're.sub('`. (We use `--null` and `-0` in order to correctly handle file names that contain spaces.)

Its output in a directory with all three of the above files is:

```
import-with-sub.py
7:re.sub(something)
```